# Visual Studio debug iterators

Tags: c++, visual-studio

What is the relation between [_SECURE_SCL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985896.aspx) and [_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985939.aspx).
Is it possible to turn on/off range checking and preserve binary compatibility?

Any difference between 2008 and 2010 versions?

Comment: Stephen T. Lavavej of Channel 9 did a lecture about this not too long ago.  Not sure if it answers your question, but it might be interesting to you none the less. http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Advanced-STL-3-of-n

Comment: @Benjamin: That was the first thing that came to mind, directly after reading _SECURE_STL and _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stephan Lavavej has provided some detail on this `_SECURE_SCL` and `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING`:

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/08/10/the-future-of-the-c-language.aspx

> Iterator debugging, enabled by
>   _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING, performs powerful correctness verification. 
>   Iterator checking, enabled by
>   _SECURE_SCL, performs minimal checks that serve as a last line of security
>   defense.  For example, _SECURE_SCL
>   will terminate a program that triggers
>   a heap overrun with a vector iterator.
>
> All that is explained by MSDN
>   documentation.  The story behind this
>   is interesting.  The
>   _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING functionality was provided by Dinkumware, the
>   company that licenses their most
>   triumphant implementation of the
>   Standard Library for inclusion in
>   Visual Studio.  The _SECURE_SCL
>   functionality was added by Microsoft,
>   in order to improve the security of
>   programs running on Windows.  In order
>   to perform their checks, both
>   _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING and _SECURE_SCL make iterators contain additional data members, such as
>   pointers to their parent containers. 
>   _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING, because it is enabled by default in debug mode (and
>   not obtainable in release mode), also
>   builds singly linked lists that allow
>   containers to refer to all of their
>   iterators.  This is expensive
>   performance-wise, but performance is
>   not critical in debug mode, and this
>   enables excellent checks.
>
> _SECURE_SCL, because it is enabled by default in release mode, strives to
>   impose minimal performance penalties. 
>   Therefore, when it is enabled,
>   although iterators have pointers back
>   to their containers, containers don't
>   have pointers to their iterators. 
>   (Updating "iterator lists" is too
>   time-consuming for release mode.)

Note that starting in VS 2010, `_SECURE_SCL` is no longer enabled by default in release mode (the above excerpt is from 2007).

As described in this bug report (http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/334315/has-iterator-debugging-0-causes-crash), both `_SECURE_SCL` and `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` affect the ABI:

> _SECURE_SCL and _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING significantly change the behavior and
>   representations of STL containers and
>   iterators. VC9 (Visual Studio 2008)
>   made the representations of STL
>   containers and iterators even more
>   strongly dependent on _SECURE_SCL and
>   _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING (this was done to fix a conformance bug).
>
> Because these macros change the
>   representations of STL objects, you
>   must observe certain rules when
>   changing these macros from their
>   defaults. I described the rules here:
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2007/08/10/the-future-of-the-c-language.aspx#4617984 To summarize, the macros must be
>   consistent within each binary (EXE or
>   DLL), and furthermore, binaries that
>   pass STL objects to each other must
>   have consistent macro settings. Your
>   example involves an EXE and DLL
>   passing a vector between
>   themselves, so the EXE and DLL need to
>   have the same _SECURE_SCL and
>   _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING settings.
>
> These rules apply to VC8, VC9, and all
>   future versions. Your code happened to
>   work with VC8 (Visual Studio 2005),
>   but would fail if it did more
>   complicated things.

Comment: Maybe add an explanation on _ITERATOR_DEBUGLEVEL, which is new in VS2010.

Comment: Just FYI for anyone coming across this answer later: as noted, in VS2010 the checked iterators were disabled in Release mode, but then in VS2012 they were enabled again, and in VS2013 disabled again.  Not sure why the apparent mixed feelings.