# Why can't I delete an element in my vector?

Tags: c++, vector, erase

I've got a fairly long program I'm working on and am having difficulty deleting an element from a vector.  I've tried to do it with a very simple vector, and am having the same problem.  As far as I can see, I've done it the same way everybody has explained in other people's questions.  Here is the simple code.

```
vector<int> vect;
vect.push_back(3);
vect.push_back(2);
cout << vect[1];  // prints '2'
vect.erase(vect.begin()+1);
cout << vect[1] << endl; // prints '2'
```

What am I doing wrong?

It seems the above code works, because I checked the size at the end, and it printed '1'.  The real  code doesn't though:

```
size = A[i]->B().size();
cout << "size is " << A[i]->B().size() << endl;  // prints 21
A[i]->B().erase(A[i]->B().begin()+size);
cout << "size now " << A[i]->B().size() << endl;  // prints 21
```

I can't see what I've done differently?  A is a vector, which stores other vectors.  I want to delete the last element in the B vector.

Comment: +1 for producing a simple example ;)

Comment: You forgot to explain what _different_ behaviour you expected!

Comment: @Sandra Regarding your edit, `A[i]->B().begin()+size` points to *one beyond the last element*. So, that line reads `A[i]->B().erase(A[i]->B().end());` and nothing is erased. To erase the last element, `A[i]->B().pop_back();`

Comment: I've edited my question with my actual code - I'm expecting the last element in 'B' to be deleted.

Comment: @Praetorian I changed it to begin()+size-1 and it is still size 21 on the last line.

Comment: @Sandra [Here's](http://liveworkspace.org/code/708ddae898a6a461f91da52b6adea514) a demo (I'm using C++11 features, but that's not relevant). Anyway, to remove the last element, use the `pop_back` member function.

Answer (score 5):

After you erase your element, your vector's size becomes 1 (because it was 2 before the erasing), essentially making your expression `vect[1]` result in undefined behavior, because there is no element with index `1` any more. All is left is a single element (value = 3, index = 0). If you used `vect.at(1)` instead of `vect[1]`, it would throw `std::out_of_range`.

After your edit:
Remember, if the size is `N`, then `N` is not a valid index for the vector!!! The elements are indexed `0, 1, 2, ... N-1`. So indeed, the size is `1`, therefore the only valid index is `0`

Comment: Thanks... I was aware that you could still access the location, but wasn't aware of 'at'.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is *undefined behavior*. Basically, you are accessing past the currently last element of the vector, and you happen to find garbage that was left here. The problem is made evident using `at` instead of `[]` for accessing the element because `at` has built-in range checking.

```
// cout << vect[1] << endl;
cout << vect.at(1) << '\n';
```

If you replace `[]` by `at` as above, you will get a `std::out_of_range` exception signalling that the index you provided is invalid.

Comment: Ha, I was adding the part about at in my answer when you posted yours. +1

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: I just wish that C++ was safer by default and `[]` had range checking while `at` did not. Newbies are irremediably drawn to the lighter weight syntax (so reminiscent of arrays in plenty of other languages) and run afoul of undefined behavior in a heart beat :(

Comment: I believe MSVC does perform range checking for `operator[]` in Debug builds by default. That is a handy feature to have, and you don't pay the penalty for the check in Release builds.

Comment: @Praetorian: Dirkumware's implementation contains a number of checks that can be activated using [`_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103314/visual-studio-debug-iterators) or `_SECURE_SCL`. If I remember right, in case of violation you will hit an `assert` and your program will abort.

Answer (score 1):

To delete the last elemnt in a vector, you can use `.pop_back()`. Also you should note that adding integers to an iterator is a bad idea. Use `vector<int>::iterator` instead as your variable to add.